# “In App” Payment solution for Wordpress Plugin

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing, wordpress-plugin-creation

I’d like to allow my clients to pay for items within a plugin, on their dashboard. Im calling this “in app”.

I am building a plugin for a number of clients. The plugin allows my client to offer their customers my (printing) services. For existing customers I manually invoice clients at the end of a month for varied costs incurred. I’m aiming to increase the number of clients who use my services and I’m keen to keep the admin to a minimum, how might I incorporate a payment gateway for “in app” / “in plugin” payments. Allowing the client, shop owner, to pay for my services in the Dashboard > Orders screen.

Can anyone recommend a route for me? Client could either continue to pay on a monthly basis with some script keeping tally and raising an invoice.

Alternatively the payments would be required, following a new order notification. Could be taken with a pop-up within the Dashboard > Orders screen where I currently have a custom column allowing for management of each job (my print service).

One hack; I could use a PayPal HTML button and pass the amount via some JS script, this wouldn’t allow for tracking successful payments / clever feedback… and I’d rather use Stripe etc.

I have searched around and found it difficult to find any existing devices as the question clashes with info regarding payment gateways in general. Please do let me know if this is possible.

Comment: As a start and in order to integrate Stripe you can start following these guides in order to implement accepting Payments.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?client=html&lang=php

Sorry not familiar with Wordpress but you can refer also to Woocommerce Stripe plugin:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-stripe

Comment: That is kind, I am proficient at integrating Stripe with Woocommerce checkouts (allowing customers to pay for goods purchased on a WooCommerce shop) using their payment gateway plugin. In the scenario I was attempting to outline it is the admin of the shop I wish to accept payments from (charges for services I provide to their customer), from the dashboard / administration panel of their wooocommerce install.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Stripe have an fantastic SDK. It has allowed me to build an entirely customised payment gateway, the payment element of which I inject into client’s Woocommerce orders screen by way of a modal and an old fashioned iFrame. My plugin is proof of concept at the moment so this is fine if inelegant.